Stop http access of DigitalOcean droplets which are behind load balancer
There are three DigitalOcean droplets(x.y.z.1, x.y.z.2, x.y.z.3) are running with a nodejs services on port 8000. All these three droplets are running behind a load balancer(XX.YY.ZZ.UU).  LB is able to call services from droplets.
We want to stop the direct access of services from droplets (http:/x.y.z.1:8000) except LB.
How we can perform on DigitalOcean platform


Traffic coming from LB usually has source IP addresses of LB instead of original sender and IP address of the original sender can be forwarded by using X-Forwarded-For header field. Therefore, by blocking all incoming traffic on port 8000 on firewall at all 3 droplets, except from LB’s IP, direct access can be stopped. On DO portal select Droplet -> Networking -> Firewall.
Configuration with 3 droplets in one datacenter has a huge single point of failure problem, better solution is 3 droplets in 3 different datacenter and some GSLB or advanced Client-side GSLB solution for load balancing and HA.
